# What is the proper way to style an iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I started fiddling with an iframe here:

http://jsfiddle.net/M68GL/3

`<iframe id="test" width="400" src="http://www.digg.com"></iframe>`

I want to get rid of the scroll bars and the strange border but can't figure out how to do it.

According to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

the use of the scrolling attribute is deprecated in HTML 5.

Also I see no attiribute for the border.

Can I just give the element an id and style it using CSS?

Using HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use `frameborder="0"` to get rid of the border, but just using `border:0` in CSS should do it too.

As for the scroll bars, you can try adding `overflow:hidden`, but usually it's the child document that needs to specify that on its `html` element. If you don't control the child document, then you can't stop scrolling with CSS and will need to use the deprecated attribute instead.

Comment: why would they deprecate something so useful and not replace it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as expected, cross-browser incompatible as of yet.  Nonetheless, here it is, a mixture of old and new:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless>
```

This may not validate in W3C, but your customers will not notice, nor will it affect negatively the operation of your page(s).